# Possibility to change URL by result i'm looking for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, stock

There is following code

```
import requests

# replace the "demo" apikey below with your own key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=EMA&symbol=IBM&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=demo'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

what i'm looking for is how to embed by request the stock symbol without changing all the time the URL code. Something like at the beginning

```
stock = input("Please enter a ticker symbol")
```

whereby `stock` equals `IBM` within the URL in this example

I thought about an approach like this but unfortunately its not working. In result i just get as a result "`{}`". Any idea?

```
import requests
# replace the "demo" apikey below with your own key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
stock = input("Please enter a ticker symbol")
url= f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=EMA&symbol={'stock'}&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=MYAPI"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

PS if you have any better economic data from the web, i'm thankful for any advice.

Comment: For economic data check this: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply when you use f-string in your program you should not use a quotation mark inside the bracket

```py
my_text = 'text'
f"{'my_text'}" # Wrong

my_text = 'text'
f"{my_text}" # True
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Perhaps you meant f'{my_text}'

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following:

```
f"....{'stock'}...."
```

is just a little fancier version of string concatenation. It is basically substituting the string instead of the variable `stock`.

It is the same as:

```
"......"+'stock'+"....."
```

If you remove the `' '`, python will now fetch its value

```
f'.....{stock}.....'
```